# Chat input is not visible while using some third-party keyboards on iOS

Tags: bug, chat, mobile-web, keyboard, ios

> [image]

> [image]

The first screenshot is using the default keyboard. You can see the input fixed to the top of the keyboard.

I'm using Gboard in the second screenshot. No matter how far I scroll, I can't see my input.